# How to decaffeinate coffee?

Tags: caffeine, decaffeinated

I was wondering how coffee is being decaffeinated.

How is this achieved? Are there different approaches? 
Since when is this practice?

Comment: Welcome to [coffee.se]. The other linked question has the answer; if your question is different (e.g., how to decaffeinate at home?) please feel free to ask another or edit this one and we can re-open.